# sendto() python

Tags: python, snmp, bandwidth, traffic, sendto

I use python program to do traffic generator in Linux Ubuntu, and the code like below:

```
import socket, sys

host = sys.argv[1] #Server IP Address
textport = sys.argv[2] #Server Binding Port

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) #socket

try:

    port = int(textport)

except ValueError:

    port = socket.getservbyname(textport, 'udp')

while 1:

   try:
        data = open('auth3.log')#read file

        for each_line in data: #each rows
                try:
                        (role,line_spoken) = each_line.split(': ',1)#split two parts
                        role  =  role.strip()
                        s.sendto(role, (host, port))
                        print('Send: ' + str(role) + "\n" )
                except:
                        pass

    except IOError as err:
        print('file isn\'t exist!!~'+str(err))

    finally:
        if 'data' in locals():   #If data have no object, Don't use data to close!!~
                data.close()

    print "\n"
```

The size of auth3.log is about 1.8M.

When I send data to the destination server, I use snmp which OID is ''ifInOctets'' to get the traffic information.

But I the traffic recalculate to unit of ''Kbits'' is about 128.

How can I use this program to fill the bandwidth up to 1Gbits?(In other words, I want to fill out the bandwidth)

Thanks for your helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This version of your code implements the first two optimizations suggested by Chris Merck.

```
import socket, sys, itertools

host = sys.argv[1] #Server IP Address
textport = sys.argv[2] #Server Binding Port

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

try:
    port = int(textport)
except ValueError:
    port = socket.getservbyname(textport, 'udp')

# preprocess file data    
with open('auth3.log') as data:
    roles = [role for (role, line_spoken) in line.split(': ', 1) for line in data]

# preprocess everything we can
hp = (host, port)
send = s.sendto

for role in itertools.cycle(roles):
    try:
        send(role, hp)
    except:
        pass
```

For further optimizations, you might want to process it using [Cython](http://www.cython.org/), which might further speed up the loop. If the code still doesn't generate enough traffic, you'll probably need to launch several processes in parallel.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Does the means about ''launch several processes in parallel'' is the way I need to do multi-thread processed in this program?

Comment: @WayneHong I meant that you can start more than one instance of the whole program. Have you measured the bandwidth usage with this version?

Comment: So I need to use the object oriented programming to create more than one instance which is the object in class? The bandwidth is about 600Mbits which I tested by Netperf.

Comment: Thanks again. 
Your answer is help, but I'm new in stackoverflow, I feel sorry for that I don't have enough reputation to up vote your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your program is not running fast enough to generate 1Gbps on the wire.

To make it run faster, you can:

1. Remove the call to `print` after `sendto`. (Print is slow by nature.)
2. Preprocess your `auth3.log` file so that you do not need to process it within your inner loop. (Right now you are looping on `.split` and `.strip`, both of which are wasting CPU time.
3. Rewrite your program to send larger chunks.

But, I fear the result will *still* not reach 1Gbps. To really max out your line, try using a traffic generation program such as [Colasoft Packet Builder](http://www.colasoft.com/packet_builder/index.php) (although I'm not sure even *that* program will do it. 1Gbps is a *lot* of traffic.)

Comment: Thanks for your replying again, I modify the code and try to use the traffic generation program (Colasoft Packet Builder) that you mentioned. But I think it can't specify the destination IP address which be sent packet? If it is, then maybe it'll be the tool I need.